# Finding float average of random list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, average

I have looked on several websites, books, and in the documentation and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I try to ask for help as a last resort, so that I can learn on my own, but I have spent far too long trying to figure this out, and I am sure it is something really simple that I am doing wrong, but I am learning. The code produces a single different result every time it is ran. The code produces the following error: 
26.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 7, in 
tot = sum(rand)/len(rand)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
import random
for x in range (10000):
   rand = random.uniform(10, 100)
   print(round(rand, 1))

   tot = sum(rand)/len(rand)
   print (round(tot, 1))
```

Comment: The `random.uniform()` function returns a random floating point number. That is a single value of type `float`. It doesn't return a list of random numbers, so you can't sum it and you can't get its length.

Comment: are you generating a single list or new list in each iteration?

Comment: I am generating a new list in each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually generating a list, you're generating individual values.
Do you really want to print out 10000 values along the way to your final result?

If the answer is "no!", then your code can be reduced to:

```
import random

N = 10000
print(round(sum(random.uniform(10, 100) for _ in range(N)) / N, 1))
```

or, if you prefer to break it out a little bit more for readability:

```
import random

N = 10000
total = sum(random.uniform(10, 100) for _ in range(N))
average = total / N
print(round(average, 1))
```

If this is beyond the scope of what you've learned, you can create `total` outside the loop initialized to zero, update it with each new value as you iterate through the loop, and then calculate the final answer:

```
import random

N = 10000
total = 0.0
for _ in range(N):     # use '_' instead of x, since x was unused in your prog
    total += random.uniform(10, 100)
average = total / N
print(round(average, 1))
```

This avoids wasting storage for a list of 10000 values and avoids the `append()` you're not yet familiar with.  Of course, if you need the 10000 values later for some other purpose, you'll need to tuck them away in a list:

```
import random

N = 10000
l = [random.uniform(10, 100) for _ in range(N)]
total = sum(l)
print(round(total / N, 1))
```

---

**Addendum**

Just for jollies, you can also do this recursively:

```
import random

def sum_of_rands(n):
    if n > 1:
        half_n = n // 2
        return sum_of_rands(half_n) + sum_of_rands(n - half_n)
    elif n == 1:
        return random.uniform(10, 100)

N = 10000
print(round(sum_of_rands(N) / N, 1))
print(sum_of_rands(0))  # returns None because nothing is being summed
```

Splitting the problem in half (on average) in each recursive call keeps the stack to O(log N).

I'd actually advise you to stick with list comprehension or looping, but wanted to show you there are lots of different ways to get to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

In the sum function you must parse an iterable object but you're parsing a float object.
To avoid this error you should put two last lines outside the for loop and append `rand` to a list. I don't know if it's what you want to do but it shows you how use `sum`:

```
import random
l = []
for x in range(10000):
    rand = random.uniform(10, 100)    
    l.append(rand)
    print(round(rand, 1))

tot = sum(l)/len(l)
print(round(tot, 1))
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without appending rand? Sorry, this work, I am just trying to see if I can get it to work without using things that I haven't covered yet?

Comment: you can use random.sample which returns x numbers of the given list for example rand = random.sample(range(0,100), 10000) returns a list containing 10000 numbers randomly picked in the [0, 1, 2, 3, .... 98, 99] list (range(0, 100)